# Persist Dynamically added rows +jquery and server side validation on dynamically added rows

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

With a requirement to add/delete rows dynamically to a table, i used the following jquery to add/delete rows to/from a table:
Here i resolved the problem to change the name attribute of the input tag .
But i am facing problem while fetching the post data results (while server side validation) in the same table on adding dynamic rows.
Is there a way to set dynamic php script as value attribute to the input tag?
Also, how to persist dynamically added rows on post refresh?

$(document).ready(function(){
    //This line clones the row inside the '.row' class and transforms it to plain html.
    var clonedRow = $('.row').clone().html();

```
//This line wraps the clonedRow and wraps it <tr> tags since cloning ignores those tags
var appendRow = '<tr class = "row">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';  

//$('#btnAddMore').click(function(){
//this line get's the last row and appends the appendRow when it finds the correct row.
  //    $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
    //});

$("#btnAddMore").click(function() {
    $(".employmentHistoryForm tr:last")
        .clone()
        .appendTo(".employmentHistoryForm")
        .find(':input')
        .attr('name', function(index, name) {
        return name.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(fullMatch, n) {
        return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    })
});

//when you click on the button called "delete", the function inside will be triggered.
$('.deleteThisRow').live('click',function(){
    var rowLength = $('.row').length;
    //this line makes sure that we don't ever run out of rows.
    if(rowLength > 1){
deleteRow(this);
}else{
$('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
deleteRow(this);
}
});

function deleteRow(currentNode){
$(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
}
});
```

Comment: Lloks like i soved the problem atlast. It was more of a PHP problem, the data got persisted once i used an array to the name attribute of the input tag and got the POST data response back on the same page.